# How to show that $1+\tan^2(x) = \sec^2(x)$?

Tags: trigonometry

During my math class of yesterday, our teacher asked us to prove the following:

$1 + \tan^2(x) = \sec^2(x)$ [Or if you prefer, $\sec^2(x) = 1/\cos^2(x)$]

And the teacher has forbidden us to use trigonometric entities except for the basic ones(sin(x), cos(x) and tan(x)). So, he pretty much wants us to derive it from a mere triangle.

I have tried for an hour of substitution and everything but I haven't found the solution yet.

Could anyone help?

PS: If you could edit the formulas to make them "better" it'd be very appreciated, I haven't figured out how to format math symbols on here yet.

Comment: Are you allowed to use that $\sin^2(x) + \cos^2(x) = 1$?

Comment: What your teacher wants is for you to draw a right triangle with one of the angles being "x" and the adjacent side being "1". What does that make the length of the opposite side? The hypotenuse?

Comment: Please check [MathJax Tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to learn how to type formulas on the site.

Answer (score 1):

We have $\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)=1$. Divide both sides by $\cos^2(x)$ and rearrange to get your required result.